# Blocking a thread until some piece of code finishes execution in C

Tags: c, windows, multithreading

In my C program, I have 2 threads and both are started in the beginning. I have a global variable(some handle) and that is modified in Thread1 function. Thread2 function also using that global variable. I want to make sure that Thread2 function should use that variable after Thread1 finishes updating the variable.

I want to block thread2 when thread1 updates the value of the global variable.

How to implement the above logic?

Comment: Look at using an event and WaitForSingleObject

Comment: Goolge is your friend. I would start with these keywords: "mutex" (multiplatform) or "Critical section" (Windows)

Answer (score 3):

If you're using `pthread` library, you can use mutexes to block access to a variable to other threads until you release it.

You might want to take a look to this [StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10161425/posix-c-threads-mutex-example-dont-work-as-expected)
or this [example](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19683-01/806-6867/sync-12/index.html)

By the way, some code would be better to identify what you are trying to do.

Comment: Note the example code has thread 2 working with a copy of the global variable via get_count(). This minimizes how much code is run under a mutex in both thread 1 and 2.

Answer (score 0):

If the goal here is for both thread 1 and thread 2 to run in parallel but synchronized, then use something like this example that uses semaphores (windows example):

```
int count;
    /* thread 1 */
    for(count = 0; count < 20; count++){
        /* allow thread 2 to use count */
        ReleaseSemaphore(semaphore2, 1, NULL);
        /* ... use count here */
        /* wait before count++ */
        WaitForSingleObject(semaphore1, INFINITE);
    }

    /* thread 2 */
int done = 0;
    while(!done){
        /* wait for count to be updated */
        WaitForSingleObject(semaphore2, INFINITE);
        /* ... use count here */
        done = count < 19 ? 0 : 1;
        /* allow thread 1 to update count */
        ReleaseSemaphore(semaphore1, 1, NULL);
    }
```